# In MySQL, how to set col1's value to col2's value when col2 and col3 values are not NULL?

Tags: mysql, sql, copy

In MySQL, how to set col1's value to col2's value when col2 and col3 values are not NULL?

```
UPDATE t SET col1=col2 WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL AND col3 IS NOT NULL;
```

Is this going to work?

#### solutions

1) use transaction

2) use temporary table

3) test simple case at sqlfiddle

Comment: If it breaks the db, it's going to cost my life, --- for the next few days ...

Comment: You don't have a test db setup?

Comment: That's a machine I don't have power to create db.

Comment: You can backup the table before you execute the command.

Comment: Is there a way to "test run" the SQL query on the production db just to see the effect "at a small scale"?

Comment: For example, `UPDATE t SET col1=col2 WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL AND col3 IS NOT NULL LIMIT 2;` will only at most affect 2 rows, but how do I know which two changed?

Comment: @user001 You could use transaction, and if you use non-transaction engine, you could just create a test table to test it.

Comment: I don't think its a good idea to run on the production db before running it on testing db.

Comment: I know, but I'm forbidden to create db or tables on this machine.

Comment: I set up a test table locally called t, with col1 col2 and col3. Set up test data of test, null null, test test2 null and test, test3 test 4 for data. Ran your query, and record 3 changed to test3 test3 test4. So it appears to work as written, YMMV and you run this at your own risk.

Comment: @xdazz So, I'd just do `BEGIN;`, `UPDATE t SET col1=col2 WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL AND col3 IS NOT NULL;`, <verify correctness>, `COMMIT;`.  Is that right?

Comment: If you can't create tables on that machine, setup a mysql installation on your local machine. It's a really bad idea to have no test bed.

Comment: +1 @JohnP.  It's simple to install something like, say, XAMPP and have a whole web server to test with, MySQL and all.  Beats risking your life with the production site/db.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Yep this is perfectly legitimate. In future try running stuff in SQL Fiddle, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6fb42/1

Answer (score 1):

ok, you're administering a db but have no sandbox environment to test... :(

> create database sandbox;
>
> mysqldump realdb tablename > dump.sql
>
> mysql sandbox < dump.sql

voila, there's your sandbox environment to play in :)

EDIT:

i just saw that you can't create new db. Have you thought about temporary tables?

> You can use the TEMPORARY keyword when creating a table. A TEMPORARY table is visible only to the current connection, and is dropped automatically when the connection is closed. This means that two different connections can use the same temporary table name without conflicting with each other or with an existing non-TEMPORARY table of the same name. (The existing table is hidden until the temporary table is dropped.) To create temporary tables, you must have the CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES privilege.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

EDIT 2:

I forgot the simplest solution: (***DON'T DO THIS WITH MYISAM TABLES, JUST ON INNODB!!!***)
Disable autocommit, try what you want, do a few selects to check if that's what you wanted and simply rollback if it's not working.

Comment: Why can't one use transaction if the db stores with MYISAM engine?

Comment: @user001: MyISAM doesn't support transactions, last i heard.  So MySQL might *pretend* to start a transaction, but in reality it'd be making non-rollback-able writes to the table.

Comment: @cHao is absolutely right here. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engines.html
There might be good reasons to use non-transactional tables, I just don't happen to know any of them :D

Comment: @GergelySzilagyi: One good reason is that because it doesn't have to support rolling back (and thus doesn't have do all that versioning and such), MyISAM can be screaming fast.  if you don't really need ACID (and a lot of applications would gladly give it up in favor of sheer performance)...

Comment: @cHao : sure, sure... I just wanted to point out that in an environment where `If it breaks the db, it's going to cost my life` using myIsam is rather strange. (on the other hand: if you don't need acid the db server is an overkill in itself. If you want speed, at least be oldschool: handwritten assembly with direct memory access for the whole address space :D you **know** that you can squeeze a few more bytes in the VGA controllers memory as well :) )

Comment: I get error `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE \`col2\` IS NOT NULL AND \`col3\` IS NOT NULL' at line 1`,  when running `UPDATE t SET \`col1\`=\`col2\` WHERE \`col2\` IS NOT NULL AND \`col3\` IS NOT NULL;`

Comment: you used `UPDATE t SET col1=col2 WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL AND col3 IS NOT NULL;` ?

Comment: Yes, except that I added `\`\`` around `col1`, `col2`, and `col3`.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM t WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL AND col3 IS NOT NULL;` works fine?

Comment: BTW, I'm using `5.0.96 MySQL Community Server (GPL)` on Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: provided you have an id column, i would try subselect syntax: `UPDATE t SET col1=col2 WHERE t.id IN (SELECT id FROM t WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL AND col3 IS NOT NULL);` . That's my last idea for today, it's getting late here :(